# PGSQL Help, SELECT Row Binding

Tags: sql, postgresql

i want to ask about postgresql, i couldnt find my answer from google.
Okay, lets get started,

suppose i have a table named 'name' with 20 rows, which has the column 'first_name' and 'last_name'.

what SQL i should use to make the query return only one column that contain all the value in 'first_name' and 'last_name' so that it return 40 rows (20 from 'first_name' and another 20 from 'last_name')?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `UNION` operator and aliasing the columns to the same name, as below:

```
SELECT 
first_name AS names
FROM name
UNION
SELECT 
last_name AS names
FROM name;
```

However the UNION operator will remove duplicate name, to include everything, including duplicate names use the `UNION ALL` operator as below:

```
SELECT 
first_name AS names
FROM name
UNION ALL
SELECT 
last_name AS names
FROM name;
```

Comment: `UNION` will filter out any duplicates, so there will be fewer than 40 results if any of the names occur more than once. This may or may not be what @Luckatme wanted. If duplicates should appear in the query result, use `UNION ALL` instead.

Comment: Very valid point @markusk, I've edited my code above for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to transpose columns to rows:

```
SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[first_name, last_name]) AS name
FROM name;
```

This approach will do a single sequential scan on the table, while the `UNION ALL` approach will do two scans. Which approach performs better is likely to depend on your data.